# Cannot find "Realtime Updates setting page under Facebook Apps Setting"

Tags: real-time-updates

I am trying to get real time posts from a facebook page and the article http://trocolate.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/realtime-update-in-asp-net-mvc-facebook-template/  talks about a way to implement it in asp .net mvc with a facebook template. It has the below section

Subscribe to changes

There are two ways to subscribe to a class of objects: you can do manually from App Settings or you can do programmatically by codes. Here let’s pick the easy one. Go to the Realtime Updates setting page under Facebook Apps Setting. I cannot seem to find this page.

When I go to the Apps – Settings, I get Basic, Advanced and Migrations tabs. Please let me know if I have missed something.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that article is outdated and now Facebook doesn't let you do that from Settings.

If you read the [current documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.1), it says "Real Time updates are subscribed to by using the /{app-id}/subscriptions Graph API edge." It doesn't mention any other way of making subscriptions.

Maybe you should do it programmatically.